# How to return 3 rows always even if there is no enough data

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

Is it possible to return always 3 rows? even if there are no data existing?

so i have two tables, i always need to return 3 rows so that i don't need to worry in creating a logic, if ever that i can do this on just a query then i can save time.

user table

```
|user_id| name | status|
1         bob      1
2         alice    1
3         maria    0
```

transfer table

```
id| user_id|transfer_name|
1      1        test1
2      1        test1
3      1        test1
4      1        test1
5      1        test1
6      1        test1
7      2        test1
8      2        test1
9      2        test1
10     2        test1
```

here is my current query

```
SELECT superstar.user_id,superstar.name,superstar.ranking FROM (
  SELECT transfer.user_id,user.name,COUNT(transfer.transfer_name) AS ranking 
  FROM transfer AS transfer
  LEFT JOIN users AS user ON user.id = transfer.user_id 
  GROUP BY transfer.user_id
  UNION SELECT 'N/A'
) AS superstar
LIMIT 3;
```

what if there is only two rows? i still want to return 3 rows. i tried using UNION but i am having an error of `The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`
and i feel that i am doing it wrong. any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT superstar.user_id,superstar.name,superstar.ranking FROM (
    SELECT transfer.user_id,user.name,COUNT(transfer.transfer_name) AS ranking 
    FROM transfer AS transfer
    LEFT JOIN users AS user ON user.id = transfer.user_id 
    GROUP BY transfer.user_id
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'N/A', 'N/A', 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'N/A', 'N/A', 0
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'N/A', 'N/A', 0
) AS superstar
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: hi sir it work, i will accept it after the 8minute time, but can you explain your query sir? just for the 3 union all.

Comment: If your query doesn't return any rows then 3 rows will be added because of UNION ALL, UNION will return only distinct row but UNION ALL will returns all the rows

Comment: thank you sir, but i have one last question if there is no data, the first is returning null and the second and third row has a value of ```N/A``` how can i fix that the first should return N/A too

Comment: You can use `superstar.user_id IS NOT NULL`